# How to add a default splash screen without the use of .htaccess

Tags: php

I'm looking for a method to suspend access to a website without loosing the old files, by adding a file to the directory but not .htaccess, since the use of .htaccess has been disabled on the specific server. Are there other ways to do this by using php or another method?

Answer (score 1):

rename your www-root directory and add another, empty one.

Comment: And this adds a splash screen how?

Comment: @Marc well, it will not for the pages other than root. However, it's the only reliable solution in circumstances the OP put in

Answer (score 1):

You have to rename your `index.php`, create a new one, and add:

```
<?PHP header("Location: http://disney.com"); // or something ?>
```

Also, you may want to check Apache's DirectoryIndex directive, the order of the "default page" is defined here. If your server have `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php`, the html extension is prior to the php, so You can create a file `index.html` with:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Jump page</title>
<meta http-equiv="REFRESH" content="0;url=http://disney.com"></HEAD>
<BODY>
Jumping
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

But if You want to "remove" all files recursively, You have to move the whole directory. Another option is to rewrite the url `http://yourpage.com/hidden_directory/` to somewhere, but sadly You need .htaccess to do that, if You can't access the webserver's config file. If You can:

```
<Directory /path/to/dir/>
            RewriteEngine On
            RewriteRule ^/hidden_directory/$  http://disney.com [L}
</Directory>
```